# Client Server Program in Java ( no proper output) [No errors]

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket, java-io

I was executing a client server program in netbeans and I was not getting a proper output. If any of you all could find out if there is any mistake in the code it will be very helpful.

Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author amirt
*/
public class client {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {
     String fname, s1;
     System.out.println("\n Enter the file name");
     Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
     fname=read.next();
     Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",802);
     Scanner cinp=new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
     PrintStream cps=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
     cps.println(fname);
     while(cinp.hasNextLine())
     {
         System.out.println(cinp.nextLine());
     }
 }

}
```

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author amirt
 */
public class server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String fn;
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(802);
        Socket s11=ss.accept();
        Scanner sinp=new Scanner(s11.getInputStream());
        fn=sinp.next();
        Scanner sf=new Scanner(fn);
        PrintStream p1=new PrintStream(s11.getOutputStream());
        while(sf.hasNextLine())
        {
            p1.println(sf.nextLine());
        }

    }
}
```

Output:
Enter the file name

a1.txt

a1.txt

PS: a1.txt contains: abcdefgh

Thank You!

Comment: The error is that your client sends nothing to your server, so your server doesn't receive anything. This should not be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

In your server code, instead of:

```
Scanner sf=new Scanner(fn);
```

you should write:

```
Scanner sf=new Scanner(new File(fn));
```

The `Scanner` will now read from the file's *content* instead of from the file *name*.